# How to re-order or alphabetize RDP connections in Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

On Mac OS Sierra, I can download Microsoft Remote Desktop in the App Store.  I add a lot of connections to PCs, but they are in random order.  How do I alphabetize or re-order the list of PCs?

Comment: have look @ beta ver https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/ & look over new features since you might need beta version it might support what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Microsoft Remote Desktop app for Mac doesn't support that. As suggested, the upcoming beta does.

Comment: The new Microsoft Remote Desktop 10 works as described.